# mySql: how could i select every first or second row in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example in first table i have such data: id | text

```
1 | ololo
1 | ololo_thumb
2 | here
2 | here_thumb
```

and i must select for each id first or second row, and put to second table , where i have such structure:

```
id | img | img_thumb
```

for example:

```
1 | ololo | ololo_thumb
```

could i do this in mysql, and how could i write something like %2 ?

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  There is no such thing as "the first row" unless a column defines the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select id, min(text), max(text)
from table t
group by id;
```

You can put this into a second table using `insert`:

```
insert into table2(id, img, img_thumb)
    select id, min(text), max(text)
    from table t
    group by id;
```

Comment: insert into `modx_ms2_products`(`id`, `image`, `thumb`)
    select `product_id`, min(`file`), max(`file`)
    from table `modx_ms2_product_files`
    group by `product_id`;  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table modx_ms2_product_files group by id' at line 3 Also i need update action, not insert

Comment: @brabertaser1992 . . . remove the word `table` from your `from` clause.  That is meant to be the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tr=mysql_query("select * from table")  
$tr1 =mysql_fetch_assoc($tr);
```

for the  first value  you c can  write

```
$tr1['value']
```

and for  the  last one you can fetch as

$th =end($tr1)